# How can I create a list of cards with input values using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project in which a doctor has to create a schedule. It consists of checkboxes of days in a week. The doctor can check (in a checkbox) those days on which he will be available in the hospital.

(screen shots are posted at the bottom)

```
state= { 
      days: ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
      availableDays: []
}

daysChecked= (e,i) => {
  let checkbox= document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')

  let arr= this.state.availableDays

  if(e.target.checked) {
    arr.push(e.target.value)

  }
  else{
    filterValue = arr.indexOf(e.target.value)
    arr.splice(filterValue, 1)
    filterIndex= index.indexOf(i)
    index.splice(filterIndex,1)
 }
 this.setState({
   availableDays: arr
 })
}
render() {
return(
  <div className='available'>
    <h3 className='availableDays'>Available Days</h3>
    <div className= 'available-days'>
      {this.state.days.map((day,i) => (
        <label key={i} className= 'days'>
          <input type='checkbox' className= 'checkbox' onClick={ (e) => this.props.daysChecked(e,i) } value= {day} />{day}</label>
        ))}
    </div>
  </div>
)
 }
}
```

The `daysChecked()` method pushes the checked days into the state `availableDays` array.

Then, by using the `map` function, I created cards. On each card, a user can set time  (from - to):

```
  state= {
hour: ['H',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
min: ['M','00',30],
period: ['','AM','PM']

}

render() {
    return(

  <div className='timeslots'>
    <h3>Time Slots</h3>
    {
      this.props.availableDays.map((day,i) => (
        <div key={day} className='timeslots-array'>
          <p className='timeSlots-day'>{day}</p>
          <div className= 'set-time from'>
            <select className= 'time from-hour'  >
              {this.state.hour.map((e,i) => (
                <option key={e}>{e}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
            <select className= 'time from-min' >
              {this.state.min.map((e,i) => (
                <option key={e}>{e}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
            <select className= 'from-period'  >
              {this.state.period.map((e,i) => (
                <option key={e}>{e}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
          <p>TO</p>
          <div className= 'set-time to'>
            <select className= 'time to-hour'  >
              {this.state.hour.map((e,i) => (
                <option key={e}>{e}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
            <select className= 'time to-min' >
              {this.state.min.map((e,i) => (
                <option key={e}>{e}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
            <select className= 'to-period'  >
              {this.state.period.map((e,i) => (
                <option key={e}>{e}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
          <a id={i} className='timeslots-button' ><i className="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
          <div className= 'timslots-display'>

          </div>
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
)
  }
}
```

Now, if a user set time on a card and press '+' button then that time should be displayed below the '+' button on that card.
So how make that happen.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you let me know what was your approach and the issue you faced in that?
Also, you are setting the FROM & TO time by the same action which I believe is overwriting the data.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, when u checked 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' a "daysChecked()" method called which pushed those checked elements into an array of state object name "availableDays" 
So from availableDays with the help of map method i created those 3 cards (which you can see in another screenshot).
Now my problem is if i set time eg: 2: 00 AM - 3: 00AM on a card then after pressing the '+' button that time should be displayed on that card below the '+' button

Comment: ```this.props.updateFromHour(e,i), this.props.updateFromMin(e,i) & this.props.updateFromPeriod(e,i)``` What do these functinos do? Can you show the code of this? It's better if you can add the code to a public repository and sahre the link of it.

Comment: I am sorry, i was trying to solve the problem myself but could not able to and forgot to delete that before posting this on stackoverflow.... so now i deleted those methods and edit my code again.

Comment: What you are doing is fundamentally wrong in a React standpoint for the initial implementation. Please study this section on controlled forms/components first
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: you can use ```<select value={this.state.selectedData}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({selectedData: e.target.value})}>``` to get the selected option value

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    hour: ["H", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    min: ["M", "00", 30],
    period: ["", "AM", "PM"],
    days: [
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
    ],
    availableDays: [],
    selectedData: []
  };
  daysChecked = (e, i) => {
    const { availableDays, selectedData } = this.state;
    let arr = availableDays;
    let selArr = selectedData;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      arr.push(e.target.value);
    } else {
      let filterValue = arr.indexOf(e.target.value);
      arr.splice(filterValue, 1);
      //when we unselect a day, to make the data disappear we set false to it's show property 
      selArr[e.target.value].show = false;
    }
    this.setState({
      availableDays: arr,
      selectedData: selArr
    });
  };
  saveTime = (e, id, type) => {
    const { availableDays, selectedData } = this.state;
    var newArr = selectedData;
    availableDays &&
      availableDays.map((item, index) => {
        if (index === id) {
          newArr[item] = {
            ...newArr[item],
            show: false,
            [type]: e.target.value
          };
        }
      });
    this.setState({ selectedData: newArr });
  };
  showTime = (e, i) => {
    const { availableDays, selectedData } = this.state;
    var newShowValue = selectedData;
    newShowValue[availableDays[i]].show = true;
    this.setState({ selectedData: newShowValue });
  };
  render() {
    const { availableDays, selectedData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="available">
          <h3 className="availableDays">Available Days</h3>
          <div className="available-days">
            {this.state.days.map((day, i) => (
              <label key={i} className="days">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  className="checkbox"
                  onClick={e => this.daysChecked(e, i)}
                  value={day}
                />
                {day}
              </label>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="timeslots">
          <h3>Time Slots</h3>
          {availableDays &&
            availableDays.map((day, i) => (
              <div
                key={day}
              >
                <p className="timeSlots-day">{day}</p>
                <div className="set-time from">
                  <select onChange={e => this.saveTime(e, i, "fromHour")}>
                    {this.state.hour.map((e, i) => (
                      <option key={e}>{e}</option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                  <select onChange={e => this.saveTime(e, i, "fromMin")}>
                    {this.state.min.map((e, i) => (
                      <option key={e}>{e}</option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                  <select onChange={e => this.saveTime(e, i, "fromPeriod")}>
                    {this.state.period.map((e, i) => (
                      <option key={e}>{e}</option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </div>
                <p>TO</p>
                <div className="set-time to">
                  <select onChange={e => this.saveTime(e, i, "toHour")}>
                    {this.state.hour.map((e, i) => (
                      <option key={e}>{e}</option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                  <select onChange={e => this.saveTime(e, i, "toMin")}>
                    {this.state.min.map((e, i) => (
                      <option key={e}>{e}</option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                  <select onChange={e => this.saveTime(e, i, "toPeriod")}>
                    {this.state.period.map((e, i) => (
                      <option key={e}>{e}</option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </div>
                <button onClick={e => this.showTime(e, i)}>+</button>
                {selectedData[availableDays[i]] &&
                selectedData[availableDays[i]].show === true ? (
                  <div>
                    From-
                    {selectedData[availableDays[i]] &&
                      selectedData[availableDays[i]].fromHour}
                    :
                    {selectedData[availableDays[i]] &&
                      selectedData[availableDays[i]].fromMin}
                    :
                    {selectedData[availableDays[i]] &&
                      selectedData[availableDays[i]].fromPeriod}
                    <br />
                    To-
                    {selectedData[availableDays[i]] &&
                      selectedData[availableDays[i]].toHour}
                    :
                    {selectedData[availableDays[i]] &&
                      selectedData[availableDays[i]].toMin}
                    :
                    {selectedData[availableDays[i]] &&
                      selectedData[availableDays[i]].toPeriod}
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <></>
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have removed the css classes, reapply them.
Please try this and let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: can we set property like u did  "selArr[e.target.value].show = false;"
i guess we cant , right ?

Comment: @RahulRana Yes, we can set the property as we need.